# Inserting into two oracle tables with a sequence

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two tables in Oracle, job and reference.

I want to insert a new record into both tables, with a key generated from a sequence. Something like:

```
insert into (
select j.jobid, j.fileid, j.jobname, r.reffileid 
from job j
inner join reference r on j.jobid=r.jobid)
values (jobidsequence.nextval, 4660, 'name', 4391);
```

This, of course, leads to:

```
ORA-01776: cannot modify more than one base table through a join view
```

Is there a way of doing this without using PL/SQL? I'd dearly love to do it using just SQL.

Comment: Just do two inserts. The first one using `nextval` the next one using `currval` referencing the generated id.

Comment: Thanks, a_horse_with_no_name. Does that risk a problem with the sequence if another session calls nextval before my currval call is processed?

Comment: No. That's the whole purpose of a sequence. Values generated by a sequence are "session private". No two sessions will ever get the same value from a `nextval` or `currval` call (unless e.g. the sequence is configured to cycle)

Comment: Ah great, I hadn't realized they were private to the session, I imagined they were global. Thanks.

Comment: In some way they are both: "global" and "private". Calling `nextval` obviously has a "global" scope, because other sessions calling `nextval` will get a new value. `currval` on the other side is always "private".

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use a side-effect of the [`insert all` multi-table insert](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/statements_9014.htm#i2095116) syntax for this:

```
insert all
into job (jobid, fileid, jobname)
values (jobidsequence.nextval, fileid, jobname)
into reference (jobid, reffileid)
values (jobidsequence.nextval, reffileid)
select  4660 as fileid, 'name' as jobname, 4391 as reffileid
from dual;

2 rows inserted.

select * from job;

     JOBID     FILEID JOBNAME  
---------- ---------- ----------
        42       4660 name       

select * from reference;

     JOBID  REFFILEID
---------- ----------
        42       4391
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/3cb8e/1).

From the restrictions:

> You cannot specify a sequence in any part of a multitable insert
>   statement. A multitable insert is considered a single SQL statement.
>   Therefore, the first reference to NEXTVAL generates the next number,
>   and all subsequent references in the statement return the same number.

Clearly I am using a sequence in the `values` clause, so the first sentence doesn't seem quite accurate; but you can't use it in the `select` part. (I'm not 100% sure if it can be used in the `values` in all versions, but the documentation is a little misleading in any case, and contradicts itself).

So I'm taking advantage of the fact that because it is a single statement, the two references to `nextval` get the same number, as the third sentence says, so the same sequence value is used in both tables.

Comment: Thanks, I hadn't realized that nextval would return the same value. I tried putting it in the select clause and, as you said, it didn't work.

Comment: I'll use this approach, thanks. I'd tried using INSERT ALL, but hadn't twigged to being able to call nextval twice like that. I acknowledge that two separate INSERT statements would also have worked, but this one is tidier for me to implement.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `jobidsequence.currval` to get the current value of the sequence (within one session <strike>transaction, i.e. until `COMMIT`</strike> when you called `nextval` before, and until you call `nextval` again).

See: [Oracle Admin Manual: Managing Sequences](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/views002.htm)

Comment: A `commit` has no influence on the value (or accessibility) of `currval`.

Comment: The transaction has no influence on the sequence handling whatsoever. Sequence values are *session* scoped completely ignoring transactions.

Comment: From the doc you linked to: 'To use or refer to the current sequence value of your session, reference seq_name.CURRVAL. CURRVAL can only be used if seq_name.NEXTVAL has been referenced in the **current user session (in the current or a previous transaction)**'.

Answer (score 0):

simpler way ..

```
    begin
      insert into job (
        col1,
        ...
        coln)
      select
        col1,
        ....
        coln
      from
        tableA
    <condition>;

      insert into job2 (
        col1,
        ...
        coln)
      select
        col1,
        ....
        coln
      from
        tableB
    <condition>;

    End;
```

Comment: But the OP wanted a non-PL/SQL solution; and is inserting new data not selecting from existing table data; and you aren't showing how the sequence number is preserved (presumably either generating it as a local variable, or using a `returning` clause into a local variable).

Answer (score 0):

**Try like this:**

```
PROCEDURE ADD_CAMPAIGN (
                          configXML IN CLOB
                        ) IS 
        vn_CAMPAIGNID number;
BEGIN
   vn_CAMPAIGNID := CAMPAIGN_SEQUENCE.NEXTVAL;

  INSERT INTO CAMPAIGN_INFO (campaign_id,name,start_date,period,handset_statu,bscs_service_id)
  VALUES(vn_CAMPAIGNID ,
  XMLTYPE(configXML).EXTRACT('/campaign/campaignInfo/name/text()').getStringVal() ,
  TO_DATE(XMLTYPE(configXML).EXTRACT('/campaign/campaignInfo/startDate/text()').getStringVal()) ,
  XMLTYPE(configXML).EXTRACT('/campaign/campaignInfo/period/text()').getNumberVal() ,
  XMLTYPE(configXML).EXTRACT('/campaign/campaignInfo/handsetStatu/text()').getStringVal(),
  XMLTYPE(configXML).EXTRACT('/campaign/campaignInfo/bscsServiceID/text()').getNumberVal()

  );
  INSERT INTO PROMO_INFO(CAMPAIGN_ID,NAME) 
    VALUES(vn_CAMPAIGNID,
    XMLTYPE(configXML).EXTRACT('/campaign/campaignInfo/promoName/text()').getStringVal());

 INSERT INTO UTILITY_INFO(CAMPAIGN_ID,NAME)
     VALUES(vn_CAMPAIGNID,
     XMLTYPE(configXML).EXTRACT('/campaign/campaignInfo/utilityName/text()').getStringVal())  ;

 INSERT   INTO FREE_UNIT_INFO(CAMPAIGN_ID,NAME) 
     VALUES(vn_CAMPAIGNID,
     XMLTYPE(configXML).EXTRACT('/campaign/campaignInfo/packageName/text()').getStringVal()) ;

   INSERT INTO HANDSET_INFO(HANDSET_ID,NAME,CAMPAIGN_ID)
     VALUES(HANDSET_SEQUENCE.NEXTVAL,
     XMLTYPE(configXML).EXTRACT('/campaign/campaignInfo/handsetName/text()').getStringVal(),
     vn_CAMPAIGNID);



END ADD_CAMPAIGN;
```